# JavaFX on android - Hello world keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports

So I read that you can get JavaFX applications to run on Android by using the Dalvik JavaFX-Android SDK (provided by the JavaFX Android porting team) and decided to try my hand at it.

After installing the Dalvik SDK and telling it where my Android SDK is, I tried to run the sample Hello World application that comes with the Dalvik SDK. So I went into the Hello World app's folder and ran the "gradlew installdebug" command. It all went well:

[image]
<sub>(source: [forumbilder.se](http://forumbilder.se/EADB9/asdasd.png))</sub>

But when I tried launching the application on my phone it did not go so well:

[image]
<sub>(source: [forumbilder.se](http://forumbilder.se/EADB9/oiuyt.png))</sub>

Is there anyone of you that could provide an answer or maybe some speculation as to why it won't run?

Error message from Logcat:

[image]
<sub>(source: [forumbilder.se](http://forumbilder.se/EADBC/dgfhdfghfdg.png))</sub>

Comment: When you get that message in Android, the first place to go is the stack trace. People will likely need the causing error to help.

Comment: Which versions are you using (dalvik, android sdk and build tools, gradle, java JDK...)?

Comment: Regarding the stack trace, I don't even know how to view it. I'm not very experienced, sorry. Versions: Java version 1.8.0_31, dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3, Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.2, Android SDK Tools 24.0.2, Gradle 2.1

Comment: You need JDK 8u40 early release, and set JAVA_HOME with its path. For debugging, try adb tool from <android path>/sdk/platform-tools: `adb shell logcat`.

Comment: Can I use my current JDK version by downloading an earlier version of the Dalvik SDK?

Comment: No, that won't work...

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help, but sadly installing the JDK 8u40 early release and setting the JAVA_HOME variable to it didn't change anything. I have updated my post with what I think is the relevant output from Logcat regarding the crash, that thing just spews out text almost non-stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70930/discussion-between-just-some-guy-and-jose-pereda).

Comment: So you need to set `sdk.dir` and `javafx.dir` to their proper folders in the environment variables for it to work. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(While the problem is already solved and the application is working, this is the solution, in case anyone faces the same problem)

Once android-sdk is installed, and once you download the dalvik package (`dalvik-sdk-8u40-ea3` or new releases), to create the apk for the samples in that package, it's required to update a file named `local.properties` for each sample.

This file should contain the path to android sdk and to dalvik-sdk.

Then, from command line `gradlew installDebug` will create the apk and install it on the device.

Also, it comes in handy logging the messages from the device, not only in case the app crashes but also in case of unexpected behavior, or to check any `System.out.println()`.

For that, from < android-sdk path >/platform-utils running on the command line

```
adb shell logcat
```

will log the app (and others from the device).